# Migrate From Oracle Jdeveloper 12c to Jdeveloper 11gr2

Tags: oracle11g, jdeveloper

I have an adf project that is in oracle jdeveloper 12c and i want to open it on oracle jdeveloper 11gr2 . how can i do it ?
because when i want to open this project into jdeveloper 11gr2 , error in below is occur :
Unable to load the application file . Workspace CentralBankUI.jws already migrated to newer version (12.1.3.0.0.)
can any one suggest me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't move to older version like this, migration is only supported going forward.
You also might be using features that are in 12c but not in 11.
Why would you want to go to an older version?

Answer (score 0):

As Shay said there is no migration for previous release, you have to change code manually
For reference you can see -[Case Study: Backporting a JDeveloper Project from11gR2 to 11gR1](http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/case-study-backporting-a-jdeveloper-project-from11gr2-to-11gr1/)

Bdw 12C is much better than previous release and has lots of new feature and compoennt

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install the desired version to a separate folder. Use that installation to open the application at hand.